# which hostname or ip is java rmi bind in linux?

Tags: java, rmi

i am new with java rmi. And i have a question about rmi usage.
Firstly, i created a server with port(the interface only has a port argument).

```java
this.registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
```

Then i bind a server like this:

```java
public interface MyRmiService extends Remote {
    // return "service name" for example
    String getName() throws RemoteException;
}

 public void register(MyRmiService service) {
        try {
            this.registry.rebind(syncDataService.getName(), service);
        } catch (RemoteException var3) {
            FineLoggerFactory.getLogger().error(var3.getMessage(), var3);
        }

}
```

and my client code is like this:

```java
// linux ip
Registry tempRegistry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(ip, 1099);
MyRmiService service = (MyRmiService)tempRegistry.lookup("service name");
```

These code looks fine if my machine ip looks the same with linux shell:

```
[root@node26 ~]# hostname
node26
[root@node26 ~]# hostname -i
192.168.101.26
[root@node26 ~]# hostname -I
192.168.101.26 192.168.122.1 172.17.0.1
```

if i use 192.168.101.26 as ip.
But if i get some different ip like this:

```
# for example
[root@a ~]# hostname -I
172.16.5.199 172.17.0.1 
[root@iZbp124z80qrl3rd8pk42xZ ~]# hostname -i
10.162.107.99
[root@iZbp124z80qrl3rd8pk42xZ ~]# hostname
iZbp124z80qrl3rd8pk42xZ
```

It doesn't work fine and stuck in the client finding service with `lookup`.
Normally i want to use `172.16.5.199` as ip. But maybe rmi is using `10.162.107.99` which i cannot ping from client. Is this linux server has the right hostname config?
Then I'm confused.

1. which hostname or ip is used when `LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);` called?
2. which hostname or ip is used when `registry.rebind(syncDataService.getName(), service);`called?
3. which ip should i use to call `LocateRegistry.getRegistry(ip, 1099);` ?
   My question is, what exactly the ip should i use?

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a problem description, but if 172.16.5.199 is a public IP address, it won't work through your router unless it has port forwarding enabled suitably. To answer your specific questions: (1) "localhost"; (2) the same as you provided when you called `createRegistry()`; (3) if the RMI server and client are both in the same host, "localhost", otherwise if they are in the same LAN, the LAN IP address of the server, otherwise its public IP address, if port forwarding is enabled.

Answer (score 3):

TLDR: **it's not the registry**

To get your first and third questions out of the way

- the registry created by `LocateRegistry.createRegistry` (like the one created by running the `JRE/bin/registry[.exe]` *program*) listens on 0.0.0.0 for IPv4 and/or ::0 for IPv6 depending on your JVM config. This can receive on any address (and over any interface) that works in your OS.
- `LocateRegistry.getRegistry(String[,int])` connects to whatever address or name (resolved to an address) you specify; `([int])` calls `InetAddress.getLocalHost()` which dispatches to `getLocalHostName()` in `Inet4AddressImp` or `Inet6AddressImpl` depending on your JVM as above, but in either case that is a native method with implementation depending on your OS which for Unix including Linux is [here](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/unix/native/libnet/Inet4AddressImpl.c#L61) or [here](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/unix/native/libnet/Inet6AddressImpl.c#L62). As you can see these are identical and thus it always calls [`gethostname()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/gethostname) which should return the same value the `hostname` progam (with no options) displays; if the call fails (returns nonzero) Java substitutes the literal string `"localhost"`. That name is then resolved, typically by a host file and/or DNS but may vary depending on the OS and configuration; on a properly configured system `gethostname()` will be a name that resolves to a valid address of the machine (displayed by `hostname -i`), while `localhost` is special-cased to always give the loopback address (for the IP version) which is a valid address only when used on the same machine i.e. not really RMI. (A properly configured OS also resolves localhost to loopback, but Java does so here even if the OS doesn't.) Note that none of these look at the addresses actually existing on your interfaces (which `hostname -I` returns).

That connection, to the registry, worked fine. You say it's the `lookup` call that hangs, and that is trying to connect *to the remote service*. This relates to your second question about `registry.rebind(name, remoteobject)` -- but it's not the `rebind` (or `bind`) call that sets the location of the remoteobject, rather the remoteobject *already* contains its location. You use a parameter `service` without showing where it comes from and particularly where it was created, and that's what matters, because such an object is created to contain a [`LiveRef`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.rmi/share/classes/sun/rmi/transport/LiveRef.java) which in turn creates and contains a [`TCPEndpoint`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.rmi/share/classes/sun/rmi/transport/tcp/TCPEndpoint.java) which contains the name or address to be used to connect it.

Now the code in `TCPEndpoint` which determines that name or address is a bit complicated. The simple case is that if sysprop `java.rmi.server.hostname` is set, that is used -- and can be either a resolvable name *or* an address in string form. Otherwise it calls `InetAddress.getLocalHost()` as described above for `getRegistry` and by default it uses the resulting *address*, but if sysprop `java.rmi.server.useLocalHostName` is set `true` it uses the name (i.e. from `gethostname()`) except if the name doesn't contain a dot (doesn't 'look like' a DNS name) it attempts reverse resolution on the address and if successful uses *that* name; it's not quite clear to me what happens if that fails, and I can't easily test right now.

So the simple answer to your problem, but not your question, is use `java.rmi.server.hostname` to specify a name or address that the client(s) should use to reach your server.